# How to pass Form value with uploadify

Tags: php, javascript

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#file_upload").uploadify({
            'uploader'      : '/wp-content/plugins/amazon-s3-simple-upload-form/files/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'script'    : '/wp-content/plugins/amazon-s3-simple-upload-form/files/uploadify/uploadify.php',
            'folder'    : '/uploads',
            'auto'      : true,
            'buttonText'    : 'Browse',
            'cancelImg'     : '/wp-content/plugins/amazon-s3-simple-upload-form/files/uploadify/cancel.png',
            'fileExt'       : '*.*',
            'fileDataName'  : 'file_upload',
            'simUploadLimit': 2,
            'multi'         : true,
            'auto'          : true,
            'onError' : function(event, ID, fileObj, errorObj) {alert(errorObj.type+"::"+errorObj.info);
},
            'onComplete'    : function(event, ID, file, response, data) { console.log(file);}
        });
    });
```

That is my JS File....

```
<?php
/*
Uploadify v2.1.4
Release Date: November 8, 2010

Copyright (c) 2010 Ronnie Garcia, Travis Nickels

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
THE SOFTWARE.
*/
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-config.php');
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-includes/wp-db.php');


error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1); 

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['file_upload']['name'];
    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions

                global $current_user; 
                $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
                $userid = $current_user->ID;
                $username = $current_user->user_login;
                $email =  $current_user->user_email;
                $first_name = $current_user->user_firstname;
                $last_name = $current_user->user_lastname;
                $upload_time = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
                $upload_url =  $targetFile;
                $s3userIP = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
                $description = $_POST['filedesc'];

if  (move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile))
{
    $insertuser = mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_110504s3userDBinfo( upload_time, user_name, email_add, description, upload_url,s3_userIP) values  ('$upload_time','".$username."', '".$email."', '".$description."', '".$upload_url."', '".$s3userIP."')") or die(mysql_error());
                   }

    }
?>
```

That is Uploadfiy.php 
And the url is [Uploadify URL is](http://www.prowin-tv.net/s3-upload-forum/)

Actually i am using worpress cms i want this into wordpress please check whats problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in your uploadify.php script. you must modify your input file name to Filedata or you must modify in uploadify.php `$_FILES['Filedata']` with `$_FILES['file_upload']`

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['file_upload']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    echo str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$targetFile);

}
```

(file_upload is your `<input type='file' id='file_upload' name='file_upload' />`)

edited:

you must add this to your script:

```
'onSelect'      : function(event,ID,fileObj) {

          $('#file_upload').uploadifySettings('scriptData',{filedesc:$('#filedesc').val()});

        }
```

like this:

```
jQuery("#file_upload").uploadify({
        'uploader'      :       'uploadify.swf',
             'script'               :   'uploadify.php',
        'folder'                :   '/wp-content/uploads',
        'auto'              :   true,
        'buttonText'            :   'Browse',
        'cancelImg'     :   'cancel.png',
        'fileExt'       :   '*.*',
        'fileDataName'      :   'file_upload',
        'simUploadLimit'        :   2,
        'multi'         :   true,
        'auto'          :   true,
        'method'        :       'post',
        'onComplete'    :   function(event, ID, file, response, data) {},

        'onSelect'      : function(event,ID,fileObj) {

          $('#file_upload').uploadifySettings('scriptData',{filedesc:$('#filedesc').val()});

        }

    });
```

your problem was that you were setting the scriptData on init, and at that time your description was null. So I updated the scriptData value onSelect event

you get errors but you can't read them, so put them into txt file.
put this in your uploadify.php after this line

```
$insertuser = mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_110504s3userDBinfo( upload_time, user_name, email_add, description, upload_url,s3_userIP) values  ('$upload_time','".$username."', '".$email."', '".$description."', '".$upload_url."', '".$s3userIP."')") or die(mysql_error());

    $flname= "testFile.txt";
    $flHandle= fopen($flname, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $wr = fwrite($flHandle,mysql_errors());
    fclose($ourFileHandle);
```

if you're running this on a server(not localhost on windows) you have to set permissions

for this script. After this open the txt file and read the errors. If you want to be sure that the parameters are received correctly by php, you can make a dir with the description sent name.

in uploadify: mkdir($_POST['filedesc']);

Comment: Boss I have not problem with uploading file uploading sucessfully, but i need data put into mysql filename inserted successfully into mysql but problem is that i have description text area i need add description into mysql table how can pass values into upload.php with scriptdata, but how please help me

Comment: Thank you George, I have updated this into my script now i have new problem facing, progress bar not running also file could not uploaded

Comment: for me is working this code. Post your entire code from your file and also uploadify.php

Comment: your problem is that you don't initialise a connection to database and the error is not shown. you can put the errors in a txt file. see my updated answer

Comment: no sir that is include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-config.php');
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-includes/wp-db.php');
Connection files and also file inserted into mysql table but just description not inserted

Comment: do you have skype, so i want to directly talk with my skype is umershaikh79

Comment: ok, we can talk in a couple of hours because now I have some work to do

Comment: Ok Thank you Very Much i will wait for you

Comment: George is a Great Man, Thank you George for help me

Comment: How can I do this using Uploadifive?